# Should an object test if a user can edit it, or should a controller do a lookup? MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, user-permissions

My database looks like this:

**[Table] UserProfile**

- UserName

**[Table] Category**

- CategoryId (PK)
- UserName (link to UserProfile - this is the record owner)
- ProductID (FK to Product Table related records)

**[Table]Products**

- ProductId (PK)
- CategoryId (Navigation Property)

A logged on user can only edit Categories and Products that they own. I'm happy enough doing a lookup on Category based on the User.Identity.Name and CategoryID received by the Controller from the view, if I don't get a record back then it doesn't exist or the user doesn't own it. I've started to think this isn't the best way to do it, but it works...

My question relates to the best way to handle this type of check on Products?

1. Should I have a query that uses the navigation property to ProductId to then get the `UserName` value?
2. Should this be done by a linq query in the controller or a method on the Products class? i.e `prod.ConfirmOwnerIs(User.Identity.Name)`
3. Should this be an external helper method like `Helpers.ConfirmUserCanEditObject(prod, User.Identity.Name)`?

This example is slightly simplified, my real data model is several layers deep. This is a learning project for me so I'm trying avoid doing something that will hit the DB unnecessarily or in an inefficient way, or become a beast to maintain and test. I'm hoping for some guidance and wisdom here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need good security, I would have both objects and the controller do it - the object just throws a fatal exception, while the controller should make sure the user interface doesn't ever allow the user to get into a situation where the exception would be thrown.

Basically, good security needs to be simple, it should be two statements "do we have xxx permission?" And "die right now".

Since that's not user friendly enough you also put complex controller code in to handle things nicely, but this should not be considered part of your security system.

Comment: So what I'm reading here is that the object should really be asked if a particular user can modify it and the controller will act accordingly, is that what you mean? Said another way, the object implements security and the controller uses that implementation. If so would each object walk up the tree to find the root and check who owns the root record? Would you implement that query for each object or implement a method that checks one level up and call it recursively (on each parent object until you're at the top)?

Comment: No, that's not what I miean. You should have an auth system in place which is completely separated from the rest of your code, and it should be possible to ask it, with a single statement, whether or not the currently logged in user can do a specific thing (such as view object of type "foo" with the id 42). Your object should do it, and throw an exception if it returns false, and your controller should do it but bounce to a login form. Your auth code shouldn't know how the rest of your code works, and the rest of your code shouldn't know how auth works. This will reduce bugs/security holes.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do something pretty complicated. Don't do that, complexity leads to bugs and you can't afford bugs where security is concerned. Find a much simpler way to solve the problem. For example, if user "bob" is allowed to view a photo with id "42" then there should be a record somewhere such as {user: bob, type: view-photo, id: 42}. If that record exists, then bob can view the photo.

Comment: Also, don't forget to have a few unit tests to make sure those exceptions are thrown. It's less important and more difficult to test if the controller always bounces users to the login form, but as long as the object throws an exception you know everything is safe.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I am actually trying to not do something complicated if I can help it, so I appreciate your comments. There are only two levels of access in my app, full or none - and it's only based on ownership. I'm not sure adding a full access control system is going to simplify things for me... I just need an easy way to figure out if the logged on user owns a record, but it could be 4 or 5 relationships deep from the root record which contains the 'OwnerId' field. Is it terrible to have an 'OwnerId' field on all my model entities?

Comment: If possible, I would always pick using a separate database completely for each owner (lots of bugs otherwise... as i've learned the hard way). But when that isn't a viable option then yeah having an owner id on each entity is fine as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 3):

This type of check is a cross-cutting concern and would be better implemented in an ActionFilter in my opinion.

Comment: Could that be done with a single ActionFilter for different entities at different depths of the hierarchy? Meaning could I generalise the implementation or would I need a different ActionFilterAttribute for each entity? I agree it is cross-cutting, I just can't visualise how to implement it cleanly.

Comment: It's possible to generalize it. You could implement an interface like `IOwnable` which exposes an `Owner` property on your models. Then for the action filter, you could have a named property for the name of the target action parameter that should be checked for ownership. Alternatively, you could specify the type of the target action parameter that should be checked or even just have it check all parameters if the parameter implements `IOwnable`

Comment: So would that 'Owner' property actually contain the 'OwnerId' from the database, or would it have logic to go find the 'OwnerId' from the parent record? It would be easy if every model entity had an 'OwnerId' field, but that feels wrong. What should the domain model look like here?